# How to apply List in one field with MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have this POJO :

```
public class PlayerDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String past;

}
```

And I have this entity :

```
public class Player {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> past;

}
```

How can I map the `List<String> past` into the `String past` of the DTO wih MapStruct ? For example the List is containing [ Monty , Boto , Flaouri ] and the String of the DTO has to contain "Monty, Boto, Flaouri" in a single String.

This classic way doesn't work with the target and source :

```
@Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "past", source = "past"),
})
PlayerDto entityToDto(final Player entity);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to define a default method in your mapper interface to handle data conversion from `List<String>` to `String`. Mapstruct will automatically use the default method.

The default method signature for your mapping should be like this :

```
String map(List<String> past)
```

Example :

```
default String map(List<String> past) {
    return past.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but where can I use it ? In the `@Mapping` ?

Comment: `MapStruct` will detect the default method automatically and use it. You don't have to declare it, just put the method in your mapper interface. In your generated file, you should see something like this `playerDto.setPlayer( map( player.getPlayer() ) );`

Comment: I am just testing now. I have this error idk why : `Can't map property "java.lang.String past" to "java.util.List<xxxxxxxxxxxx.String> past"`

Comment: oh, It seems the error is different. You are trying to map `String` to `List`.If that is the case, you need to define `default method List<String> map(String past)` in your mapper.

Comment: and.. if source and target property are the same ("past") you don't have to specify `@Mapping(target = "past", source = "past")`